# How to transition hair to skin in blender

Tags: texturing, hair

I'm wondering how to make my hair transition into skin. I know that might sound confusing, so here are some pictures of my project :
[image]
[image]

I want the hair to look something like this, where it kinda fades as it goes down.
[image]

The way I'm doing it in my project is with a texture that I made, but it's not a great texture, and doesn't really give me what I'm looking for. I can't use particle hair for this because this is going to be in a game I'm making, and I don't think that having a bunch of particle hair would be very good performance-wise (plus I thought I heard somewhere that you can't use particle hair in games).

EDIT: So I think I'm looking for a gradient of sorts. Here is the UV unwrap for the portion of hair that I want to have a gradient:
[image]

I want a gradient that will go top to bottom of the UV unwrap, if that makes sense. Or is there a way to manipulate the UV so that it fits with a normal gradient? If not, then this is more of a photoshop question I guess.

Edit2: I've rearranged the UV (which turned out pretty messy, I'm not used to manually moving the UV around):

[image]

It gave me this:
[image]

Which is an improvement, but if there is a better way to do this, then I'm all ears. If not, then it's fine for my purposes.

Comment: In game hairs are usually achieved with hair cards. Did you tried that?

Comment: @Carlo No. But I don't think that's the look I'm going for with this particular character. I just want this character to have short hair, so none of the: create hair object, arrange hair object, duplicate hair object, arrange the new hair object, repeat, kind of thing. So really all I need is a way to put a gradient or something on a texture, and then use the texture to make the hair color. I'll update the question and try to explain better.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new material for the hair & a new UV map? Then enter side view and use *UV unwrap > Project from View*? You probably have to fix the transition hair <-> face. You can scale up and move the UV island so that it fits the gradient.

Comment: I ended up moving around the UV and got a decent looking result, though I do wish there was an easier way to do it.  Thank you @Blunder.